# Bind: Zone not loaded due to errors

Tags: dns-hosting, fedora-20

I'm very new to this and I have been trying to set up a DNS server but I'm keep getting the following error when I type systemctl status named.service:

zone 30.168.192.in.addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to an error
_default/30.168.192.in.addr.arpa/IN: no owner

I have followed this video step by step, but I still get the same error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=052Txlzk_7w

Linked the video since I cannot copy my files as I am using VMware.
edit: images
[db.30.168.192.in.addr.arpa.zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbDFg.png)

[db.aumentity2d.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWlVQ.png)

Comment: When creating zone files be aware that starting a line with a whitespace has special meaning and may cause errors or have unintended consequences

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no current owner name error when running named-checkzone on both forward and reverse](https://serverfault.com/questions/798031/no-current-owner-name-error-when-running-named-checkzone-on-both-forward-and-rev)

Comment: yes i checked every whitespace and the files doesnt have any extra whitespaces

Comment: In this image the soa record does start with a space or tab  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbDFg.png not with a zone name or @ shorthand for the zone

Comment: a tab, every item in that line starts with a tab, expect for the root

Comment: And starting the line with a tab is equally wrong as starting the line with a space. Also be careful to ensure that FQDN’s must be terminated with a dot `.` or the will be considered shorthand and bind will append  the zone name ,

Comment: oh right thanks, corrected the FQDN. But im confused now, how should i start the line if its not with a tab or a space?

Comment: Lines in zone files  start with a resource record name such as `example.com.` or `my-host.example.com.` or shorthand versions `@` or `my-host` See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file

Comment: By convention people do not write the soa record as a single line , there they separate the record in several subsequent lines . The Wikipedia article shows both . But you have a line `tab IN SOA ...` that should be `@ IN SOA`

Comment: Thank you!!! that fixed it, ill be more careful with that stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have is

```
$TTL 1W

      IN      SOA     aumentity3d.com.        root.aumentity3d.com. (
      3        ; serial
      1W       ; refresh after 1 week
      1D       ; retry after 1 day
      28D      ; expire after 4 weeks
      1W )    
@     IN NS  aumentity3d.com.
aumentity3d.com IN A 192.168.241.141
```

That looks nicely lined out but is incorrect.

There is no name before the SOA record. That should be

```
@     IN      SOA     ns1.example.com.        hostmaster.example.com. (
```

Where the <kbd>@</kbd> is zone file shorthand. It will be replaced by the name of the zone, or whatever zone name you would set in the $ORIGIN variable.

Then there are several other things you should be aware of:

- Whenever a hostname is unqualified, the name server will convert it to a fully qualified domain name by appending the zone name / $ORIGIN.  FQDN's are terminated with a `.` dot.
  This allows a zone administrator to use shorthand, rather than writing out `my-host.example.com.` they can use `my-host`

In other words:

`aumentity3d.com IN A 192.168.241.141` is missing the trailing `.` behind the `.com` and will be therefor be converted to the FQDN `aumentity3d.com.30.168.192.in.addr.arpa.`

- When you're using shorthand, it is good practice to explicitly define $ORIGIN.

Change your db.30.168.192.in.addr.arpa.zone  file to:

```
$TTL 1W
$ORIGIN 30.168.192.in.addr.arpa.

@    IN      SOA     aumentity3d.com.        root.aumentity3d.com. (
      3        ; serial
      1W       ; refresh after 1 week
      1D       ; retry after 1 day
      28D      ; expire after 4 weeks
      1W )    
@                IN NS  aumentity3d.com.
aumentity3d.com. IN A   192.168.241.141
141              IN PTR aumentity3d.com.
```